# Create a date from a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, syntax

I'm pretty comfortable with core data now (only been iOS Developer for 6 months) but I haven't come upon having to put a date in core data.

So here's the situation. I'm pulling data from a web service in JSON format. One of the elements that I have is a date element and I don't know the syntax for properly storing this in core data.

If that isn't clear here is an example:
 
Syntax for storing a string:

```
newDate.eventyType = NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"eventyType"], nil);
```

Syntax for storing a number:

```
newDate.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"id"], nil) intValue]];
```

So I need to know the syntax for storing a date.

Comment: Follow the below update answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

If you are extracting and storing your date from json format into `NSString` Variable then try below to convert into `NSDate`:-

```
NSString *strDate2=@"19-01-2014";
NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dt1=[format dateFromString:strDate1];
```

Comment: THAT'S what I was looking for. Thanks! I'd up vote you but I don't have enough rep as I'm pretty new to posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry. Like I said I'm new to stackoverflow so I didn't at first realize how to mark it correct. Sorry for the noobishness. But now I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered before me, to create an NSDate object from NSString one uses NSDateFormatter. The important thing to know about the date formatter is that it uses user’s locale (including calendar!) and time zone. But the dates you expect to receive are probably in one, fixed locale and in one time zone. This can cause date formatter to fail parsing the date string.

The solution to this is to set the locale and the time zone to the date formatter explicitly:

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX”];
rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd”;
rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

See [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for more detailed explanation.